# How to prevent Zeroconf 0.0.0.0 in Gentoo linux?

Tags: linux, routing, gentoo

Oddly enough, it seems that one of the servers we have doesn't like having the 0.0.0.0 configured and it prevents it from being able to community on its internal network.
Removing this route manually by using:

> route del -net XXX.XXX.XXX.0/27 gw 0.0.0.0

(the XXX resolve to our IP numbers and are irrelevant to the question)
works well and restores connectivity. However, when the machine is restarted, the route is there again and we cannot connect to the network.

How can this be removed?

What's really odd here is that it worked well for a long while and there wasn't any update/upgrade before it stopped responding. All other servers are configured the same way and don't seem to have a problem with this route.

Searching the web I've found some resources on disabling it, but they weren't for Gentoo http://www.omotech.com/blog/?p=1005

Thanks

Comment: This isn't Zeroconf. Please post your `/etc/conf.d/net` file.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think zeroconf is responsible for this in the first place?

The only route zeroconf should install would be one to 169.254.0.0/16. See RFC 3927. Your issue is not due to zeroconf.

It's not due to avahi, either. Avahi is a multicast DNS implementation. It's used with zeroconf because a network lacking any intentional addressing will lack also lack a DNS server and multicast DNS could be used to provide adhoc name resolution. Avahi will not install any new routes or configure interfaces.

The route you delete is defined on what interface? Is that the interface that should be used to reach that network? Use route -n and look at the rightmost column or look for the dev attribute in the ip route output.

My hypothesis is that you have the same IP address or same subnet configuration assigned on two NICs, but only one is actually connected/working. The dysfunctional one is first in configuration order and so it's route is being used for directing packets until you remove it and the remaining, working route bound to the connected NIC is used.

I'd suggest checking with ip addr and ip route to see if you have any duplicated addressing on different interfaces; then remove or disable that configuration.

Good Luck.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't zeroconf. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is only one NIC but it's a network-specific configuration. The solution that helped was to change the /27 route to two /28 routes so they'll get priority over the default route that (due to that network's specific configuration) didn't work properly. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I found this might be helpful.

http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Avahi

Also if you don't require zeroconf you can disable avahi by doing the following:

```
rc-service avahi-daemon stop
rc-update del avahi-daemon default
```

Comment: Thanks but I've seen Avahi before and don't think it's relevant. There already IS zeroconf and I'm trying to remove this route. The server does NOT have Avahi installed so obviously removing its non-existing service won't do anything.